# How does one view documentation for an installed rubygem?

Tags: rubygems

would be nice to have `gem viewdocs InstalledGemName`, that would launch a browser to view the docs included with that gem.

Is there an easy way?  I can't find one by searching the web.

Answer (score 0):

Good option it's use `ri InstalledGemName`, you see doc in console(terminal).

Comment: gem ri gemname ( Unknown command ri ) 

ri gemname  ( nothing known about .gemname )

Comment: but doesn't launch browser with "index.html"

Comment: @peterk 
You can try next example: ri '.to_s' this command show you all gems which has this implementation.